# Insert ASCII code into string

Tags: c#, string, ascii

I want to add a horizontal tab before a string in c# and insert into a word document.
How do i append ASCII code 09 = HT ( Horizontal Tab ) at the beginning of string for word to read. Thanks.

Comment: In which language? It's different in basically every one.

Comment: @slugonamission sorry. c#

Comment: \t is the escape character for tab. See more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx

Comment: Yeah but word is not inserting a tab when i add that before the string.

Comment: First off, are you certain that Word is using that particular character?  That simply inserting that in a string would even have the desired effect?

Answer (score 1):

Is this all you mean?

```
var str= "\t" + "Hello world";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert it at the front of the string, do it like this:

```
String str = "Hello world";
str = str.Insert(0, "\t");
```